# Which components should I install to selectively download C++ requirements for Pyfolio library?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I wanted to install `Pyfolio` library but it seems like the library requires C++ build tools.

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads

I downloaded Visual Studio Community 2017 but If I check desktop dev with C++, It takes approx 6.65Gb which seems like a lot of waste of space for just one python library.

So I want to selectively install required components rather than bulk install everything related to Visual Studio C++.

Here is the list of individual components of VC installer. Which ones should I install to be able to use Pyfolio package?

Lesser the better for me since I'm drastically running out of my disk space on my laptop.

```
.NET

.NET Core runtime

.NET Framework 3.5 development tools

.NET Framework 4 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.5 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.5.1 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.5.2 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.6 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK

.NET Framework 4.6.1 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.6.2 SDK

.NET Framework 4.6.2 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.7 SDK

.NET Framework 4.7 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.7.1 SDK

.NET Framework 4.7.1 targeting pack

.NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK

.NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting pack

.NET Native

.NET Portable Library targeting pack

Advanced ASP.NET features
Cloud, database, and server

Azure Authoring Tools

Azure Cloud Services build tools

Azure Cloud Services core tools

Azure Compute Emulator

Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools

Azure development prerequisites

Azure libraries for .NET

Azure Mobile Apps SDK

Azure Resource Manager core tools

Azure Storage AzCopy

Azure Storage Emulator

Cloud Explorer

CLR data types for SQL Server

Connectivity and publishing tools

Container development tools

Container development tools - Build Tools

Data sources and service references

Data sources for SQL Server support

IIS Express

Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools

Redgate SQL Search

Service Fabric Tools

SQL ADAL runtime

SQL Server Command Line Utilities

SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB

SQL Server Native Client

Web Deploy
Code tools

Class Designer

ClickOnce Publishing

Dependency Validation

Developer Analytics tools

DGML editor

Git for Windows

GitHub extension for Visual Studio

Help Viewer

LINQ to SQL tools

NuGet package manager

NuGet targets and build tasks

PreEmptive Protection - Dotfuscator

Static analysis tools

Text Template Transformation
Compilers, build tools, and runtimes

.NET Compiler Platform SDK

C# and Visual Basic Roslyn compilers

C++ Universal Windows Platform tools for ARM64

C++/CLI support

Clang/C2 (experimental)

IncrediBuild - Build Acceleration

Modules for Standard Library (experimental)

MSBuild

Python 2 32-bit (2.7.14)

Python 2 64-bit (2.7.14)

Python 3 32-bit (3.6.6)

Python 3 64-bit (3.6.6)

Runtime for components based on Node.js v6.4.0 (x86)

Runtime for components based on Node.js v7.4.0 (x86)

Runtime support for R development tools

VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop

VC++ 2017 version 15.4 v14.11 toolset

VC++ 2017 version 15.5 v14.12 toolset

VC++ 2017 version 15.6 v14.13 toolset

VC++ 2017 version 15.7 v14.14 toolset

VC++ 2017 version 15.8 v14.15 toolset

VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools

VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 Libs for Spectre (ARM)

VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 Libs for Spectre (ARM64)

VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 Libs for Spectre (x86 and x64)

Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable Update

Visual C++ compilers and libraries for ARM

Visual C++ compilers and libraries for ARM64

Visual C++ runtime for UWP

Visual C++ tools for CMake

Windows Universal CRT SDK

Windows XP support for C++
Debugging and testing

.NET profiling tools

C++ profiling tools

JavaScript diagnostics

Just-In-Time debugger

Test Adapter for Boost.Test

Test Adapter for Google Test

Testing tools core features
Development activities

ASP.NET and web development tools

C# and Visual Basic

C++ Android development tools

C++ iOS development tools

Cookiecutter template support

Embedded and IoT Development

F# desktop language support

F# language support

F# language support for web projects

JavaScript and TypeScript language support

JavaScript ProjectSystem and Shared Tooling

Microsoft R Client (3.3.2)

Mobile development with JavaScript core features

Node.js development support

Node.js MSBuild support

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Python IoT support

Python language support

Python web support

R language support

Razor Language Services

Visual C++ for Linux Development

Visual C++ tools for CMake and Linux

Visual Studio C++ core features

Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)

Windows Communication Foundation

Windows Workflow Foundation

Xamarin

Xamarin Remoted Simulator

Xamarin Workbooks
Emulators

Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (global install)

Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (local install)

Google Android Emulator (API Level 25)

Google Android Emulator (API Level 27)

Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) (global install)

Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) (local install)

Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Windows 10 Mobile Emulator (Anniversary Edition)

Windows 10 Mobile Emulator (Creators Update)

Windows 10 Mobile Emulator (Fall Creators Update)
Games and Graphics

Cocos

Graphics debugger and GPU profiler for DirectX

Image and 3D model editors

Unity 2018.1 64-bit Editor

Unreal Engine installer

Visual Studio Android support for Unreal Engine

Visual Studio Tools for Unity
SDKs, libraries, and frameworks

Anaconda2 32-bit (5.2.0)

Anaconda2 64-bit (5.2.0)

Anaconda3 32-bit (5.2.0)

Anaconda3 64-bit (5.2.0)

Android NDK (R11C)

Android NDK (R11C) (32bit)

Android NDK (R12B)

Android NDK (R12B) (32bit)

Android NDK (R13B)

Android NDK (R13B) (32bit)

Android NDK (R15C)

Android NDK (R15C) (32bit)

Android SDK setup (API level 19) (local install for Mobile development with JavaScript / C++)

Android SDK setup (API level 21) (local install for Mobile development with JavaScript / C++)

Android SDK setup (API level 22) (local install for Mobile development with JavaScript / C++)

Android SDK setup (API level 23) (global install)

Android SDK setup (API level 23) (local install for Mobile development with JavaScript / C++)

Android SDK setup (API level 25)

Android SDK setup (API level 25) (local install for Mobile development with JavaScript / C++)

Android SDK setup (API level 27)

Apache Ant (1.9.3)

Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET

Cordova 6.3.1 toolset

Entity Framework 6 tools

Graphics Tools Windows 8.1 SDK

Java SE Development Kit (8.0.1120.15)

Microsoft distribution OpenJDK

Modeling SDK

TypeScript 2.0 SDK

TypeScript 2.1 SDK

TypeScript 2.2 SDK

TypeScript 2.3 SDK

TypeScript 2.5 SDK

TypeScript 2.6 SDK

TypeScript 2.7 SDK

TypeScript 2.8 SDK

TypeScript 2.9 SDK

TypeScript 3.0 SDK

TypeScript 3.1 SDK

USB Device Connectivity

Visual C++ ATL (x86/x64) with Spectre Mitigations

Visual C++ ATL for ARM

Visual C++ ATL for ARM with Spectre Mitigations

Visual C++ ATL for ARM64

Visual C++ ATL for ARM64 with Spectre Mitigations

Visual C++ ATL for x86 and x64

Visual C++ MFC for ARM

Visual C++ MFC for ARM with Spectre Mitigations

Visual C++ MFC for ARM64

Visual C++ MFC for x86 and x64

Visual C++ MFC for x86/x64 with Spectre Mitigations

Visual C++ MFC support for ARM64 with Spectre Mitigations

Visual Studio SDK

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10240.0)

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586.0)

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393.0)

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for Desktop C++ [x86 and x64]

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP: C++

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for Desktop C++ [ARM and ARM64]

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for Desktop C++ [x86 and x64]

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for UWP: C++

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17134.0)

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)

Windows 8.1 SDK

Windows Universal C Runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the VS build tools, i.e. no IDE, command line interface, you can download them from [Microsoft's download page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) .